# href for downloading an excel file

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel, download

My server generates excel files dynamically. I am using AJAX to download the dynamic excel file. In success callback, I receive the excel file data.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: exporting.action,
            headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("key : " + key) },
            type: "post",
            success: function(res){
                 //res is the excel file that needs to be downloaded
                 //I know we can download image using anchor tag but not sure about excel file
            },
            data: { 'Model': JSON.stringify(modelClone) }
        });
```

Please suggest how to use this data in the `href` attribute of anchor tag for downloading ?

Note:

1) I need AJAX for header authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve your request by adding `dataType: "binary"` and `responseType: "arraybuffer"` property.

```
$.ajax({
    url: exporting.action,
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("key : " + key) },
    type: "post",
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    dataType: "binary",
    success: function(res){
        //res is the excel file that needs to be downloaded
        //I know we can download image using anchor tag but not sure about excel file
    },
    data: { 'Model': JSON.stringify(modelClone) }
});
```

Then you receive array buffer which can be easily download via Blob and object URL.

```
var blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(objectUrl);
```

in your case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: exporting.action,
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("key : " + key) },
    type: "post",
    success: function(res){
        var blob = new Blob([res], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
    },
    data: { 'Model': JSON.stringify(modelClone) }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try

Comment: The problem is returning excel file as array buffer from server. I don't have control over the data from server. A third party library returns it directly to the client browser. I am only passing my data to the 3rd party library

Comment: is it possible to convert the data to array buffer in client-side ?

Comment: what do you have to pass to library and what is output from library?

Comment: I am passing a 3rd party chart instance. Their library will create an excel file with chart. The output is raw data of the generated excel file.

Comment: I managed to convert this data into ArrayBuffer but now there is a problem with encoding of the received data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132630. Thanks for your help