# Data encoding is different in ajax success handler

Tags: ajax, excel, encoding

I am using AJAX to download the excel file from server. But the downloaded data is different from actual data

[image]

Actual data is with orange background. Received data is in yellow background.

From the difference file, it looks like they are using different encoding formats. So excel throws error that the file is not in correct format.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: exporting.action,
        headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("key : " + key) },
        type: "post",
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        success: function (res, status, obj) {                
            var blob = new Blob([str2ab(res)], { type: obj.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') });                
            var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(objectUrl);
        },
        data: { 'Model': JSON.stringify(modelClone) }
    });
```

Please help to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with "encoding" is caused that jQuery did not response arraybuffer but string. Strings are in JavaScript UTF-16 and binary data in string cause trouble next to trouble. I recommend you to use native AJAX instead of jQuery. Code is similar and browser support is the same as the browser support of blobs and object URLS what you use.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", exporting.action);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("key : " + key));
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') });
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
    }
}.bind(this);
xhr.send({ 'Model': JSON.stringify(modelClone)});
```

Comment: Thank you very much